# How to bind ArrayList Objects to android GridView?

Tags: android, arraylist, android-gridview

I've a collection of array list objects like:

```
ArrayList<Person> persons=new ArrayList<Person>();
```

so how can i bind this list of objects `persons` to android `gridview`?

Answer (score 2):

```
  GridView settingGrid;
  ArrayList<Person> persons;
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.setting);

   persons =new ArrayList<Person>();

    settingGrid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.settinggridview);
    settingGrid.setAdapter(new SettingImageAdapter(this));
    settingGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,long id) {
             });

 public class SettingImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    Context MyContext;

    public SettingImageAdapter(Context _MyContext){
        MyContext = _MyContext;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v;
        if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
            v = li.inflate(R.layout.setting_gried_item, null);
            TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);
            tv.setText("Profile "+position);

            tv.setText(persons.get(position));

        }
        else
        {
            v = convertView;
        }
        return v;
    }

    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }


    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = { 
            R.drawable.one, R.drawable.two,
            R.drawable.five, R.drawable.four, 
            R.drawable.eight,R.drawable.seven,
            R.drawable.seven
        };
    private String[] names = {
            "Wallpaper Setting","Font Setting",
            "Sysnchronization Download","Sysnchronization Upload",
            "Change Password","Camera",
            "Gallery"
    };
}
```

And your XML like be :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/GridItem"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:layout_x="201px"
android:layout_y="165px" >


<TextView android:id="@+id/grid_item_text"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="TextView"
  android:gravity="center_horizontal"
  android:textColor="#000000">
</TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is setting.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
android:id="@+id/settinggridview" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:textFilterEnabled="true"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth" 
android:gravity="center"
android:horizontalSpacing="15px" 
android:verticalSpacing="25px"
>
```

try like this

Comment: Above sample is for binding images right? but i want to bind array list objects.

Comment: Thank you 'll try it. Also is it possible to bind this objects data to TableLayout? if so plz can you provide me sample?

Comment: Yes.  `ArrayList<Object> routeList = getWmRoute();
        tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);
  for(int i = 0; i<routeList.size();i++){
   TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
   RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
   TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
   TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
   TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
   tr.addView(rb1);
   createView(tr, tv1, ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getBusinessUnit());
   createView(tr, tv3, ((WMRoute) routeList.get(i)).getDescription());
   tl.addView(tr);}`

Comment: Thank you, i think you gave me syntax if you dont mine could you rearrange this one with my object ArrayList<Person> persons; where Person class having firstname,lastname,age because 'm new to this apps.

Comment: Where you are calling ArrayList<Person> persons some method?

Comment: Actually i'm getting list of persons from service response, so i parsed the response by using DOM technique and create a array list like ArrayList<Person> persons=new ArrayList<Person>(); persons.add(person); where person is a class object.