# Android MySQL Write Resultset to Array and then to gridview

Tags: java, mysql, bitmap, resultset

I have MySQL Table with image blobs and now I want to retrieve them and write them to an array to later show them in gridview. But my problem is that the while loop never ends.

Here are some log-files about what happens.

```
06-13 23:16:24.550  29200-29224/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:11
06-13 23:16:24.555  29200-29224/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:12
06-13 23:16:24.760  29200-29225/com.test.app                  I/System.out: com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet@41860510
06-13 23:16:24.765  29200-29225/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:11
06-13 23:16:24.780  29200-29225/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:12
06-13 23:16:25.095  29200-29226/com.test.app                  I/System.out: com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet@41fe2788
06-13 23:16:25.105  29200-29226/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:11
06-13 23:16:25.110  29200-29226/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:12
06-13 23:16:25.450  29200-29222/com.test.app                  I/System.out: com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSet@41809328
06-13 23:16:25.455  29200-29222/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:11
06-13 23:16:25.460  29200-29222/com.test.app                  I/System.out: Getting Image with id:12
```

Here is the code of my app.

```
public class Activity2CameraView extends Activity {

private static final String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://XXXX";
private static final String user = "XXXX";
private static final String pass = "XXXX";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new getImage().execute();
}

private class getImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>> {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>>();

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inDither = false;
        opt.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
                PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT id, imageblob FROM photos");
                ResultSet rset = stat.executeQuery();
                System.out.println(rset);
                rset.beforeFirst();
                while (rset.next()) {
                    ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(rset.getBytes("imageblob"));
                    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    int id = rset.getInt("id");
                    map.put("id", id);
                    map.put("image", bm);
                    mylist.add(map);
                    System.out.println("Getting Image with id:" + id);

                }
                rset.close();
                stat.close();
                conn.close();

                return mylist;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, Bitmap>> result) {
        setContentView(R.layout.cam_main);
        String[] from = {"id", "image"};
        int[] to = {R.id.id, R.id.image_db};
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(), result, R.layout.image_grid, from, to);

        // Getting a reference to gridview of MainActivity
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview_cam);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        new getImage().execute();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Add the solution of [How to bind ArrayList Objects to android GridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921870/how-to-bind-arraylist-objects-to-android-gridview) to your code and it should work...

Comment: Your `while` ends, this smell more that your method is being called a lot of times.